# Datadog replacement for local development

Tags: logging, docker-compose, containers, monitoring, datadog

I have multiple services running on the cloud for staging and prod. Locally I use a couple of docker-compose files to manage and run the services. The services' logs are reported in JSON and on the cloud, I use Datadog for log management. It's nice that I can have all logs in one place, apply filters, search and use all functionalities it offers.

But running tests or doing dev work locally is a different story, I have to switch between terminal windows to look at various logs, use Find feature of terminal which sometimes can become difficult. I'm wondering if there is an alternative I can use locally that can be easily configured to aggregate and parse container logs in one place with similar features Datadog web UI offers?

What I have tried:
I even started using `jq` to pipe logs to a nicely formatted JSON. I went even a step further and started adding filters as arguments of `jq` but that still feels different from the experience of DataDog.

I've also thought about using MongoDB or other JSON databases along with some sort of aggregator like [Telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/), but I thought maybe there is an easier way to do this.